# Django testably setting a client library based on test/prod/dev context

Tags: django, testing, configuration

I'm making calls to a particular CRM (Streak) from our backend when new user objects are created. Since new user objects are created en masse during tests, right now, our CRM gets populated with new dummy users. It's a minor pain I'd like to resolve.

Here's my prod Streak client:

```
class StreakClient(object):
    # bunch of stuff here
    def setup_client(self, client):
        #production API integration code here
        return response['boxKey']
```

Here's what I'd like:

1. Tests to not actually make production calls.
2. Counter-example: Tests for that client class itself. I have a TestStreakClient test case that needs to work with production Streak.
3. There are a number of assorted tests already in action that call the production code path by default right now. Although I could do so if it's a good long-term practice, I'd rather not have to go back and add a bunch of setUp methods.

My question is:

> How should I allow the StreakClient and DummyStreakClient classes to
>   be defined such that the above are possible?

I looked at the post office's mail.py and they seem to dynamically import a module based on a string in the settings file:

```
def get_mailbox(self)
    klass = import_string(settings.MAIL_BACKEND)
    return klass()
```

But this strikes me as being a little weird... unless it isn't. I can certainly create a new dummy Streak client and have it loaded in somehow. I could unittest / mock. Maybe something else?

Something else to note - no code really cares about the return value of setup_client. So I don't really need to go down the full intercept-calls-and-mock route here - the crm object creation succeeds or fails silently as per requirements.

Answer (score 0):

1. If Streak has no sandbox api (for tests) then you have to create fake Streak server (check Pretenders library) and test against it, that's for integration, component and end2end tests. Since unit tests has to work in isolation, then everything that is depending on StreakClient has to mock that StreakClient.
2. Unit testing of StreakClient cannot be really done well here. IMO You should make integration test for it, setup fake Streak server and test that class against it. Unit test needs to be fast and run in one process, that would mean that you have to mock http library or even deeper - sockets. This isn't good because mocking libs that you have don't own would lead to maintanance problems when lib implementation changes without Your knowledge.

PS. Setup client seems like a side effect function (command), therefore it shouldn't return anything.

Comment: Came up with a pretty straightforward solution that didn't need extra dependencies or for me to go through call interception hoops so I could create a fixture. This is fast, fulfills my requirements, and works well enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to make a specific design compromise by letting all environments call prod (except for tests) (which was fine in my case).

Then I made a custom test case superclass called `SafeTestCase`, and made all relevant test classes inherit from it (pretty small amount of refactoring work). All `SafeTestCase` does right now is safely assign a mock `DummyStreaker` so prod calls don't actually happen.

In the actual integration test for the real Streaker class, I simply don't inherit from that test case / class and let the production call happen.

```
class DummyStreaker(crm.Streaker):
    def setup_client(self, client):
        return "dummy-streak-box-key"


class SafeTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.streaker_patch = patch('offerdrive.modeldir.crm.Streaker', DummyStreaker)
        self.addCleanup(self.streaker_patch.stop)
        self.streaker_patch = self.streaker_patch.start()

    def test_setup_worked(self):
        self.assertIs(crm.Streaker, self.streaker_patch)
```